# how should I access shiny user's session info?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering if there's any way I can access user log for my Shiny App.

Currently, I use the code below to get who logged in and when did this person log off.

However, I'd prefer to know the time the user logged in so that I'm able to know how long does the user using the app.

```
session$onSessionEnded(function(){
      UserInfo <- data.frame(
                  LoginName = session$user, 
                  Time = as.character(Sys.time())
                             )
```

Plus, I understand that Google Analytics can easily access this kind of info, but I do prefer a 'shiny' way to solve it.

I've also tried to use `session$clientData' as the document says it's used for ["Getting Non-Input Data From the Client"](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html), but I don't know how could I get the login time.

Does anyone have any idea on how could I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Per the [`shiny` scoping rules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), everything inside `server <- funtion(input, output, session)` is per-session. Just add `started <- Sys.time()` as the first thing in your `server` function, and you know (within `shiny`) when that time starts.

Comment: @r2evans wow!! I never thought about it in this way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [shiny scoping rules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), everything inside `server <- function(input, output, session)` is per-session.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # everything in here is run once per-session, so it should run as soon as
  # a user starts using the app
  started <- Sys.time()
  # ... reactives here ...
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    UserInfo <- data.frame(
      LoginName = session$user, 
      Time = as.character(Sys.time())
    )
    # ... do something with UserInfo ...
  })
```

In fact, the scoping rules suggest exactly this, but they named it `startTime` instead. *(Hard things: cache invalidation and variable naming.)*